# A question about image and preimage for a set.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am currently working on a project and have a question as follows.

If Image $MX$ and Preimage $M^{-1}X$ are defined
$$MX:=\left\{Mx:x \in X \right\} , \  \ M^{-1}X:=\left\{x:Mx \in X \right\}$$
Then, for known matrices $A \in R^{n  \times \times n},E \in R^{m \times n}$ and a convex polytopic set P, $P:=\left\{x \in R^{n}:Ex \leq 1 \right\}$, then for the following statements (I am sure the first and second one are correct).
$$A^{-1}P = \left\{x \in R^{n}:EAx \leq 1 \right\}$$
$$AP = \left\{Ax:x \in R^{n}, Ex \leq 1 \right\}$$
$$AP = \left\{x \in R^{n}:EA^{-1}x \leq 1 \right\}$$
Assume $A^{-1}$ exist. Is the third one held? If so, how can I prove this?

My thought on that is to assume the second one hold, then $P = A^{-1}(AP) = \left\{x \in R^{n}: E A^{-1} (Ax) \leq 1\right\} = \left\{x \in R^{n}:Ex \leq 1 \right\}$,
Which concide the set P. Is that correct? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could focus on elements.

For $y\in\mathbb R^n$ the following statements are equivalent:

- $y\in AP$
- $\exists x\in\mathbb R^n[y=Ax\text{ and }x\in P]$
- $\exists x\in\mathbb R^n[A^{-1}y=x\text{ and }Ex\leq1]$
- $EA^{-1}y\leq1$

Comment: The third one and the fourth one really help me understand them. I have a new question that If $A$ is not invertible, how can I get similar expression for the 4th one or 3th one that you given? Does is exist not not (personally I think this probably does not exist)? If possible, could you please share some books or articles that related to these? Thank you.

Comment: Just like you I don't see a possibility if $A$ is not invertible.